# Missing from/on/in The List?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

It is missing from my list.

It is missing on my list.

It is missing in my list.

Which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: A list is normally understood as something you put things *on*, although there are also cases where it may be appropriate to talk of what is *in* a list (possibly if the list is conceived as an official register or the like). However, when something is *missing*, it is always missing *from* the list.